# Installing latest r-base from r-project

Tags: software-installation, apt

I want to learn and use R, and so I need to install it. Unfortunately, Wheezy got only 2.15 version, while I need 3.1.1. I followed these instructions:
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/
and added gpg keys, but after

```
apt-get update
apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Debian is still installing 2.15. I wonder what I did wrong. I have used my country server (Poland).
Is there a way to install 3.1.1 on Wheezy other than from source?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution, using:

```
aptitude -t wheezy-cran3 install r-base r-base-dev
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I've done to update my r-base on wheezy.

# HOW TO UPDATE r-base 2.15 to 3.x ON DEBIAN WHEEZY

add these lines at the end of "/etc/apt/sources.list"

```
deb http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/ 
deb-src http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

add the missing public key of CRAN

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 06F90DE5381BA480
gpg -a --export 06F90DE5381BA480 |sudo apt-key add -
```

update and upgrade

```
apt-get update
aptitude -t wheezy-cran3 install r-base r-base-dev
```

Comment: I suggest to indent the commands with 4 spaces (cf. markdown syntax description) for better readability.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the procedure is explained here:
http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/README.html
plus ....http://www.r-bloggers.com/upgrade-and-update-r-2-15-to-r-3-0-in-debian-wheezy/ (though the second was a bit messy, but finally all worked fine.)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Since links often go stale, [it is always preferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.